# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to ILogin

Tags: java, hibernate

```
private ILogin results;

    public ILogin authenticate(Login login) {
        System.out.println(login);
        System.out.println(login.getEmail());
        String query = "SELECT email, id FROM Login WHERE email='"
        + login.getEmail() + "' AND password='" + login.getPassword() + "'";
        results = getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
        System.out.println(results);
        return results;
    }
```

How do i change `results = getHibernateTemplate().find(query);` I get the error in this line. But i want that in ILogin type not of List type. How do i do an Type Conversion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the type conversion per se - it's that you've executed a query which may return *multiple* results, but you only want a *single* result.

You probably want to check that the resulting list has exactly one value (0 means login not found; more than 1 probably means there's a problem in your data somewhere) and then return that first value (`return (ILogin) list.get(0);`).

As a slightly separate matter, you shouldn't be including the data directly in your query like that, IMO. Use query parameters, which is pretty easy in Hibernate:

```
 String query = "SELECT email, id FROM Login WHERE email=? AND password=?";
 Object[] parameters = { login.getEmail(), login.getPassword() };
 List results = getHibernateTemplate().find(query, parameters);
 if (results.size() != 1) {
     // Probably throw an exception
 }
 // I'm assuming your mapping has been set up appropriately such that
 // the returned value will *be* an `ILogin`.
 return (ILogin) results.get(0);
```

Finally, you almost certainly don't want `results` to be an instance variable - it should probably be a local variable, as per my example above.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can u look into this issue which i am getting now after updating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646548/error-java-lang-classcastexception

Comment: Yes, but in the "new" question you haven't changed the select to not return a list. And a list cannot be cast to ILogin

Answer (score 1):

The dummy way is to use `getHibernateTemplate().find(query).get(0);` but this will result in exception in case when no such login found.

As Jon said, check your query for emptiness.

Answer (score 1):

I assume spring :).

```
List resultsList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
if ( resultsList.size() == 1 ) {
results = (ILogin)resultsList.get(0);
} else {
// error no entity or mutiple entities
}

return results.
```

This should work.